# Update mapping table in Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table `Customers` with a `CustomerId` field, and a table of `Publications` with a `PublicationId` field. Finally, I have a mapping table `CustomersPublications` that records which publications a customer can access - it has two fields: `CustomerId` field `PublicationId`.

For a given customer, I want to update the `CustomersPublications` table based on a list of publication ids. I want to remove records in `CustomersPublications` where the `PublicationId` is not in the list, and add new records where the `PublicationId` is in the list but not already in the table.

This would be easy in SQL, but I can't figure out how to do it in Linq.

For the delete part, I tried:

```
var recordsToDelete = dataContext.CustomersPublications.Where
                      (
                         cp => (cp.CustomerId == customerId)
                               && ! publicationIds.Contains(cp.PublicationId)
                      );

dataContext.CustomersPublications.DeleteAllOnSubmit(recordsToDelete);
```

... but that didn't work. I got an error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL

So, I tried using `Any()`, as follows:

```
var recordsToDelete = dataContext.CustomersPublications.Where
                      (
                         cp => (cp.CustomerId == customerId)
                               && ! publicationIds.Any(p => p == cp.PublicationId)
                      );
```

... and this just gives me another error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator

**Any pointers?**

[*I have to say, I find Linq baffling (and frustrating) for all but the simplest queries. Better error messages would help!*]

Comment: LINQ to SQL is awesome for querying a database, but it isn't really that great for updating as it has to select all the rows you want to modify and then update each object one-by-one. If you can do it in pure SQL using ExecuteQuery it will run much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Almost by chance, I discovered that the reason I couldn't use `Contains` in my first example was that my `publicationIds` was an `IList<int>` rather than a an `int[]`. I changed it, and it worked.

Thanks, compiler message author! :-|